# Angular how can I prevent the ngif update?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I have an object with many properties. I have a site where all those properties are listed with an input field connected via `[(ngModel)]` to the object. On those fields I have an `*ngIf="isEmpty(propKey)"` that checks if the propertie is empty.

I only want to show every property that currently doesn't has any value. The problem is as soon as I start to type in the input field, the field disappears because the property now has a value by pressing the first button on the keyboard. But I want to write more to it and not just a single char.

Is there a way that I can manually trigger the condition in the `ngIf` so I can update what properties are shown after I press my save button?

Comment: whats your current solution or try?

Comment: If I had a solution I would not ask here. I didn't try anything because I don't know what to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the input's [`ngModelOptions`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#properties) to update the model on `blur` or `submit`.

```html
<input 
  [(ngModel)]="myObject[prop.key]"
  [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
/>
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-76092889?file=src%2Fmain.ts) demo.

Comment: Been developing in Angular for 6 years and had no idea `ngModelOptions` existed. Thank you for introducing it to me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rxjs` stream there, and use a `Subject` as a trigger to recompute your values in `ngIf` directive. Like this:

`your-component.component.ts`

```
  ...

  name = 'Angular';

  protected readonly recomputeValue = new Subject<void>();

  protected readonly showThisProp$ = this.recomputeValue.pipe(
    map(() => this.isEmpty(this.name)),
  )

  protected isEmpty(property: string): boolean {
    return Boolean(property);
  }

  protected checkValues(): void {
    this.recomputeValue.next()
  }

  ...
```

`your-component.component.html`

```
<h1 *ngIf="showThisProp$ | async">Hello from {{name}}!</h1>
<input [(ngModel)]="name" />
<button (click)="checkValues()">Check Values</button>
```

Here is this an example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bpbvpg?file=src/main.ts)